# Redis get stuck indefinitely

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis

I am trying to connect to remote redis server using python
for that I am using version `redis==4.0.2` but when I print `redis.get`
it is stuck indefinitely.

Below's the code snippet

```
import redis

REDIS_HOST = "<remote_host>"
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_PASS = "<password>"
REDIS_DB = 2
REDIS_MAX_CONNECTIONS = 100

redis_db = redis.StrictRedis(
    host=REDIS_HOST,
    port=REDIS_PORT,
    password=REDIS_PASS,
    ssl=True,
    db=2,
    max_connections=REDIS_MAX_CONNECTIONS
)


print(redis_db.get("1_lab"))
```

This is working now, had to add ssl=True for my remote connections

Comment: It worked and edited the working code

Comment: A question becomes significantly less helpful for others if you edit out the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

It can be because the firewall will be blocking the port 6379.
Check your remote server for firewall and check if port is open.